# No response when getting a table from a web using BeautifulSoap library

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to get two data tables from a [web](https://www.avamet.org/). I'm using the BeautifulSoup Python library from Google Colab. The URL to download is the following: https://www.avamet.org/mx-consulta-diaria.php?id=%%25%%2525&ini=2024-02-27&fin=2024-02-28&token=s0141%21 You can see the two tables there!

I'm trying to do the following:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_avamet_data(START_DATE=None, END_DATE=None, region='%%25%%25'):

  # All stations: %%25%%25  -------------------------------------------> Doesn't work
  # Only the station 15: c15%25 ---------------------------------------> It works!!!

  url = 'https://www.avamet.org/mx-consulta-diaria.php?id=' + region + '25&ini=' + START_DATE + '&fin=' + END_DATE + '&token=s0141%21'

  print('Getting data from: ' + url)

  response = requests.get(url)

  web_html = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

  selector = 'table'
  tables = web_html.find_all(selector)

  table_1 = tables[0]
  table_2 = tables[1]

  data_1 = []
  for row in table_1.find_all('tr'):
    cols = row.find_all(['td', 'th'])
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    data_1.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])

  data_2 = []
  for row in table_2.find_all('tr'):
    cols = row.find_all(['td', 'th'])
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    data_2.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])

  return([pd.DataFrame(data_1), pd.DataFrame(data_2)])
```

Then:

```
a = get_avamet_data(START_DATE='2024-02-27', END_DATE='2024-02-28')

a[0]
a[1]
```

But I obtain an empty list in the `tables` variable. However when I change the region argument from `'%%25%%25'` to `'c15%25'` it works.

Where is the problem?

Comment: How exactly did you get that url?  It's strange to have two percent signs next to each other like that.

Comment: Your suggestion made me substitute %% for % and it worked. Thank you very much. I am translating a working R code using the rvest package. In R it works correctly with %%, I don't know why. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `pandas.read_html()` to scrape the tables into dataframes directly - It also fixes the issue John Gordon mentions and convert it to `%25%25%25%2525` - `requests` is not doing this, so you get a response without your expected tables:

```
import pandas as pd

def get_avamet_data(START_DATE=None, END_DATE=None, region='%%25%%25'):

  url = 'https://www.avamet.org/mx-consulta-diaria.php?id=' + region + '25&ini=' + START_DATE + '&fin=' + END_DATE + '&token=s0141%21'

  print('Getting data from: ' + url)

  return(pd.read_html(url))

a = get_avamet_data(START_DATE='2024-02-27', END_DATE='2024-02-28')

print(a[0])
print(a[1])
```

Comment: Interesting solution. It is simple and elegant. I didn't know the Pandas `read_html` function. Thank you very much.